# django migrate error, sqlite version in python3

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, sqlite, centos7

i'm try to python django tutorial in linux centos7 server.
i installed python3, pip, django, virtualenv, sqlite

```
# virtualenv -p python3 venv
# source venv/bin/activate
(venv) # pip3 install django 
Successfully installed django-2.2.1 pytz-2019.1 sqlparse-0.3.0
(venv) # django-admin startproject firstdjango
# cd firstdjango

# python3 manage.py runserver
... LookupError: No installed app with label 'admin'.

# python3 manage.py migrate
... django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: SQLite 3.8.3 or later is required (found 3.7.17).
```

problem1. sqlite3 version
i already installed latest sqlite3. version is 3.27.2

```
# sqlite3 --version
3.27.2

# sqlite3.7 --version (backup initial sqlite3)
3.7.17
```

but in python3, sqlite3 version is still 3.7.17

```
# python3 -c "import sqlite3; print(sqlite3.sqlite_version);"
3.7.17
```

how can i resolve this problem?

if you need additional information about my centos7 configuration, please reply. thank you.

OS Centos7

```
# python3 --version
Python 3.7.3

# pip3 --version
pip 19.1.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)

# pip3 list virtualenv
Package    Version
---------- -------
Django     2.2
pip        19.1.1
pysqlite3  0.2.1
pytz       2018.9
setuptools 40.8.0
sqlparse   0.3.0
virtualenv 16.4.3

# python3 -c "import django; print(django.VERSION);"
(2, 2, 0, 'final', 0)

# sqlite3 --version
3.27.2 2019-02-25 16:06:06 bd49a8271d650fa89e446b42e513b595a717b9212c91dd384aab871fc1d0f6d7

# sqlite3.7 --version (backup initial sqlite3)
3.7.17 2013-05-20 00:56:22 118a3b35693b134d56ebd780123b7fd6f1497668

# python3 -c "import sqlite3; print(sqlite3.sqlite_version);"
3.7.17

# python3 -c "import django; print(django.VERSION);"
(2, 2, 0, 'final', 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following things.

1. Lookup where this sqlite3 is present. `which sqlite3` this will give you path of this file.
2. Then rename `sqlite3 ~> sqlite3_backup`
3. Do the same for sqlite3.7. `which sqlite3.7` go to the path and rename `sqlite3.7 ~> sqlite3`
4. Then run the migrate command and see if the issue still exists.

Comment: thank you for reply. <br/>
1. `# which sqlite3 ~> /usr/local/bin/sqlite3` and version is 3.27.2 <br/>
3-1. `# which sqlite3.7 ~> /usr/bin/sqlite3.7` and version is 3.7.17 <br/>
2 and 3-2. `mv /usr/local/bin/sqlite3 /usr/local/bin/sqlite3_backup` and `mv /usr/bin/sqlite3.7 /usr/local/bin/sqlite3` is right? <br/>
I want to hearing the explanation your following codes before run these codes. <br/>
I think the version downgrade from 3.27.2 to 3.7.17. Is that right?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue where the python I installed was not compiled with the SQLLite libraries.  This only happened to me on CentOS, was never a problem on Ubuntu.  The solution was to build python from source and install it side by side with the system python.

Comment: thank you. do you know any tutorials about "build python from source and install it side by side with the system python"?

Answer (score 0):

1. Install binary version of pysqlite3 (which comes with precompiled, newer version of sqlite lib, more info: https://github.com/coleifer/pysqlite3).

```sh
pip install pysqlite3-binary
```

2. In python code, use pysqlite3 instead of sqlite3 like:

```py
import pysqlite3
    (...) conn = pysqlite3.connect(r"filename")
```